# The Number of Weak Characters in the Game. Trying custom solution

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve "The Number of Weak Characters in the Game" from leetcode.
Description of the problem:

> You are playing a game that contains multiple characters, and each of
> the characters has two main properties: attack and defense. You are
> given a 2D integer array properties where properties[i] = [attack i,
> defense i] represents the properties of the ith character in the game.
>
> A character is said to be weak if any other character has both attack
> and defense levels strictly greater than this character's attack and
> defense levels. More formally, a character i is said to be weak if
> there exists another character j where attack j > attacki and defense
> j > defensei.
>
> Return the number of weak characters.
>
> Example 1: Input: properties = [[5,5],[6,3],[3,6]] Output: 0
> Explanation: No character has strictly greater attack and defense than
> the other.

After few hours of trying, I managed to create this solution:

```
public static int numberOfWeakCharacters(int[][] properties) {
    if (properties.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i =0; i<properties.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<properties.length; j++) {
            int localCounter = 0;
            int firstValue = properties[j][0];
            int value = properties[j][1];
            if ((properties[i][0] < firstValue && properties[i][1] < value) ) {
                counter++;
                if (i+1 == properties.length) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

But here is the problem. When the if condition invokes, the statement `j = 0;` doesn't work. By the logic after finding the element, that is considered more powerful compared to current value, i increment my `i` to hop on the next element. The interesting point here, that j should start from the very beginning, but it starts from the first index.

Any ideas how to fix this bug?

Please do not suggest any other methods of solving this question. I only searching for the way to fix my own implementation.

Comment: Please add the problem/task description as it is not clear what the method is supposed to do.

Comment: When you debug your code, does it enter the inner `if`? `break` would skip the rest of the block, end the inner loop, and thus continue to the next value of the outer loop. If it doesn't enter the inner `if`, then the increment statement (j++) is run before the next inner loop.

Comment: @Martheen yes, it actually enters inner if

Answer (score 1):

I think your code would just work fine if you replace the following code:

```
if (i+1 == properties.length) {
    break;
}
i++;
j=0;
```

by a single `break;` statement.

The inner loop (`j` variable) is used to find the more powerful element. If you find the more powerful element you want to exit the loop as you only need to find one such element. The outer loop will then check the next element as the `i` variable is incremented by one.

You also do not need to check this: `if (i+1 == properties.length)` as your outer loop checks for this condition: `i<properties.length`. So, `i` cannot get larger than `properties.length`.